# Adding an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to implement a flood fill tool to a WPF paint program. I am attempting to bypass any of the vector methods by making sure every drawing action is written to the bitmap first. The bitmap is then set to the canvas.

I am having an issue when passing the image to the canvas. It does not set the image using a relative position. The images will explain much better than I can.

Before Fill:

[image: Before Fill]

After Fill:

[image]

The image bitmap is written relative to the window and overlaps the toolbar. I am wondering how I can prevent this from happening. Attached is the relevant code from my Fill class.

```
    public override void OnMouseDown(CCDrawingCanvas canvas, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        double dpi = 96d;

        // Get the size of the canvas
        System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size((int)canvas.ActualWidth, (int)canvas.ActualHeight);

        // Measure and arrange the surface
        canvas.Measure(size);
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        RenderTargetBitmap source = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)canvas.ActualWidth,
            (int)canvas.ActualHeight,
            dpi,
            dpi,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        source.Render(canvas);

        WriteableBitmap modifiedImage = new WriteableBitmap(source);
        int h = modifiedImage.PixelHeight;
        int w = modifiedImage.PixelWidth;
        int[] pixelData = new int[h * w];
        int widthInByte = modifiedImage.PixelWidth * (modifiedImage.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);

        modifiedImage.CopyPixels(pixelData, widthInByte, 0);

        int oldColor = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { System.Drawing.Color.White.B, System.Drawing.Color.White.G, System.Drawing.Color.White.R, System.Drawing.Color.White.A }, 0);
        int newColor = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { System.Drawing.Color.Black.B, System.Drawing.Color.Black.G, System.Drawing.Color.Black.R, System.Drawing.Color.Black.A }, 0);

        // Perform the recursive fill
        FloodFill(pixelData, (int)p.X, (int)p.Y, w, h, oldColor, newColor);

        modifiedImage.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, w, h), pixelData, widthInByte, 0);

        newFill = new GraphicsFill(modifiedImage);

        // Adds newFill to canvas.GraphicsList
        AddObject(canvas, newFill);

    }
```

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="ccGui.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media.Effects;assembly=presentationcore"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:ccDrawingLib;assembly=ccDrawingLib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ccGui"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">

<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
            <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save As" Command="ApplicationCommands.SaveAs" />
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Tool" Name="menuTools">
            <MenuItem Header="Brush" Name="ccToolBrush" Tag="Brush" />
            <MenuItem Header="Fill" Name="ccToolFill" Tag="Fill" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <lib:CCDrawingCanvas x:Name="canvas" Background="White" />
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: The symptoms almost look like the new object is being added to the parent or root Visual instead of the child. In general the layout system usually prevents non-relative layouts unless you're really trying or you added to the wrong parent Visual/container. Can you share the relevant XAML too?

Comment: Why on earth would you do all that manually, when you can just use the shapes classes and save the image using the [`RenderTargetBitmap.Render`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render.aspx) Method?

Comment: @JTrana I will post it soon.

Comment: @Sheridan Do you mind elaborating? I do not understand what you mean by that.

Comment: In WPF, practically all UI controls extend the `Visual` class. You can use that `Visual` reference to pass to the `RenderTargetBitmap.Render` Method to *easily* save an image of that UI control. You should investigate it to make your life easier.

Comment: @Sheridan Isn't that what I am already doing? I create an instance of `RenderTargetBitmap` and call the `Render` method.

Comment: That's a very good point... I think this sentence made me jump to the wrong conclusion: *I am attempting to bypass any of the vector methods by making sure every drawing action is written to the bitmap first*. My point is this... I guess that you're using a `Path` when drawing shapes. If this is true, then can't you just use the `Path.Fill` property to fill it? You shouldn't need to keep switching between the `Shape`s and `BitMapImage`s.

Comment: @Sheridan I get what you're saying now. The problem with filling a shape is that it would overlap line paths that are under the layer. If I make a smiley face with a black outline and red eyes and mouth, the fill could potentially overlap the eyes and mouth. I suppose it depends on the ordering. I wanted the fill to work as it would in Paint.

Comment: The answer to that is the [`Panel.Zindex` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex(v=vs.110).aspx). Set each new drawn shape to use the next higher `Zindex` value and then the latest shapes will always sit on top of the lower ones, just as in a drawing program.

Comment: @Sheridan You've been very helpful. If you want to add that info as an answer I will gladly accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, practically all UI controls extend the `Visual` class. You can use that `Visual` reference to pass to the [`RenderTargetBitmap.Render` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render.aspx) to easily save an image of that UI control. It seems to me that you shouldn't need to keep switching between the `Shape`s and `BitMapImage`s to fill your `Shape`s. I guess that you're using a `Path` when drawing shapes. If this is true, then you can just use the `Path.Fill` property to fill it in without having to do any manual calculations.

Furthermore, if you set the [`Panel.Zindex` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on each new drawn shape and use the next higher `Zindex` value each time, then the latest shapes will always sit on top of the lower ones, just as in a drawing standard program. You could even enable the users to switch the shape layers of their drawn picture using this property.